# How to change the seen status of messages in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a chat program with React, but I don't know how to implement the read status of the message.

Backend:

```js
socket.on("read_message", async({message_id})=>{
    const updated_message = await Message.findByIdAndUpdate(message_id, {is_read: true}, {new: true});
    if(updated_message){
      socket.emit("road_message", {
        status: 'success'
      })
    }
  })
```

`messageContainer` component (front):

```
const MessageContainer = ({ messages }) => {
  const messageRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const domNode = messageRef.current;
    if (domNode) {
      domNode.scrollTop = domNode.scrollHeight;
    }
  }, [messages.length]);
  return (
    <div
      id="messages"
      className="scroll-smooth flex flex-col h-full space-y-4 p-3 overflow-y-auto scrollbar-thumb-blue scrollbar-thumb-rounded scrollbar-track-purple scrollbar-thin scrolling-touch"
      ref={messageRef}
    >
      {messages.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          {messages.map((message, index) => (
            <Message message={message} key={index} />
          ))}
        </>
      ) : (
        <NoMessage />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MessageContainer;
```

message component:

```
const Message = ({ message }) => {
  const isMe = window.localStorage.getItem('user_id') === message.from;
  useEffect(()=>{
    const readMessage = ()=>{
      if (!isMe && message.is_read === false) {
        socket.emit('read_message', {
          message_id: message._id,
        });
      }
    }
    readMessage();
    socket.on("road_message", ({status})=>{
      if(status === 'success') {}
    })
  },[isMe, message])
  
  return isMe ? (
    <OutcomingMessage message={message} />
  ) : (
    <IncomingMessage message={message} />
  );
};

export default React.memo(Message);
```

I don't know how to implement it. Please help me!

Comment: Is `read_message` firing on the backend? Did you add some console logs to check?

Comment: yes, fired on the backend

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Check my below post and let me know please.

Comment: Have you checked my below post? Let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a typo in the `Message` component. `socket.on("road_message"` should be `socket.on("read_message"`.

Then, to have the read status shown on the UI, you could set a state, called `isRead` for example in `Message`, and pass it to `OutcomingMessage`:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Message = ({ message }) => {
  const isMe = window.localStorage.getItem("user_id") === message.from;
  const [isRead, setIsRead] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const readMessage = () => {
      if (!isMe && message.is_read === false) {
        socket.emit("read_message", {
          message_id: message._id,
        });
      }
    };
    readMessage();
    socket.on("read_message", ({ status }) => {
      if (status === "success") {
        setIsRead(true);
      }
    });
  }, [isMe, message]);

  return isMe ? (
    <OutcomingMessage message={message} isRead={isRead} />
  ) : (
    <IncomingMessage message={message} />
  );
};

export default React.memo(Message);
```

And `OutcomingMessage`, grab that boolean to show an indicator accordingly, something like so:

```
const OutcomingMessage = ({ message, isRead }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {message.is_read || isRead && <p>Message read</p>} <div>{message.whatever}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```